# How can I (semi-formally) convince myself that Euclidean geometry comports with visual intuition?

Tags: soft-question, euclidean-geometry

I have always felt moderately "skeptical" about the notion that Euclidean geometry as presented in a mathematics course (whether in a synthetic or an analytic form) actually corresponds to our intuitive, visual notion of flat (2d or 3d) space. By "skeptical" I of course do not mean that I actually *doubt* that it is true, I merely mean that I do not feel I have fully understood why it must be true, I have not fully convinced myself. Why, for instance, should a set like $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y=mx+b\}$ for some $m,b \in \mathbb{R}$ correspond to the visual notion of a straight line? Why should something like $\arccos(\frac{v\cdot u}{|v||u|})$ (or however we end up defining angle formally) correspond to the visual notion of the angle between two vectors? Etc. I have never felt that I had totally satisfactory answers to these questions.

Some time ago I came across [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/19156/171505) on MO, explaining why topological spaces are defined in terms of open sets. The author demonstrates in a semi-rigorous way that the properties of open sets follow directly from certain intuitions we might have about "generalized rulers". Thus, from these intuitions about "generalized rulers", we can recover the formal definition of a topological space via open sets. I have been idly contemplating how one might do something similar for Euclidean geometry—demonstrate in a semi-formal way that the basic geometrical structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$ really does capture enough of our core intuitions about flat space that the picture we all have of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in our heads is really justified. But I am not sure how to do it. Certainly, since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a model of any axiomatization of Euclidean geometry, showing that analytic geometry captures our intuitions about flat space is enough to show that synthetic geometry captures at least a subset of our intuitions about flat space.

I suspect that the "proof" here will be somewhat more complicated than the one in the linked question, as there are more intuitions to check. So I am not necessarily expecting a complete answer. But if anyone could suggest a direction in which to begin looking/thinking in order to convince myself of this fact, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is a good question. For synthetic geometry (i.e., classical Euclidean geometry), you have to believe in the axioms. After that, everything consists of logical consequences. For Cartesian geometry, you have to believe it's possible to draw two orthogonal lines with common units (to label them with numbers) and believe in the Pythagorean theorem. Then everything becomes consequences of that.

Comment: Hmm...A line is something that will rise by a uniform rate So if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a point of a line the any point that is $h$ further horizontally would be $mh$ vertically so a line is $\{(x_0 +h, y_0 + mh)|h\in \mathbb R\}=\{(x,y)| y=m(x-x_0) + y_0\}$ so.... I think this is either intuitive obvious or it isn't.  But you know... intuition blinds you make invalid assumptions.  Such intuition is certain a double edged sword.

Comment: Isn't it visually obvious that if $L_1$ and $:_2$ are (the sets of points) on two straight lines intersect at right angles then the plane that contains them, exists, is unique and is in bijection with the set of pairs $L_1 \times L_2$? In the 2d case that reduces your argument to the 1d case (and a similar argument with a line and a plane reduces the 3d case to the 1d case). So you are really asking if the standard constructions of $\Bbb{R}$ deliver something that agrees with our visual intuitions of a straight line. This is debatable, but I think can be justified.

Comment: FWIW, physical intuitions grounded in translation and rotation underlie my geometric expectations about space. Translation makes rulers and "length" possible: We carry and place objects next to other objects to compare them. <> Rotation similarly makes protractors and "angle" possible; translation lets us compare angles at different points. <> A rod can be transported "without rotating" along a path, and we observe that upon tracing a closed loop the rod's direction has not changed, giving us global parallelism. <> Now we're close to constructing Cartesian coordinates....

Comment: Now on MathOverflow: [How can I (semi-formally) convince myself that Euclidean geometry comports with visual intuition?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/467367)